# UI handler in android

Tags: java, android

Is there a dedicated UI handler for android application? how can i intercept the messages before they get handled ? im using java to write my android application. My goal is to capture UI generated events and log them.

Comment: What do you mean "UI generated events"? Like when they update or text changes? When the invalidation process occurs?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA clicks, touch, text edits. Before these events get handled i would like to log them in a file, then process them as normally

Comment: That is going to be a looooooot of data. As I said earlier though, I don't think you can. You could override `every` method in `every` object that you would like to log. Why do you want to log every action that occurs? Are you trying to debug some code or what?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA Im trying to create an event recorder for a native application. For example if i have a login application then i can record the events to login like touch,keyboard input etc... So i can reply the recorded events and the login would be automated. Im trying to minimize altering the application source as much as possible. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search i have discovered that you can capture the main looper for the application but you are not ablt eot intercept all messages that way